# Designing User related classes

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am working on the below use cases.

1. Create User
2. Delete user
3. Update User

Now I can design it in 2 ways

1. Design # 1 -- Creating UserOperations class --> Having total of 3 methods, one methods each for creating ,deleting and updating User.
2. Design # 2 -- Creating 3 Classes --> CreateUser class, DeleteUser class and UpdateUser class.

As per SRP (Single Responsibility principle) as in SOLID principles, I feel we have 3 responsibilities which are creating User, deleting User and Updating user and so we need 3 classes as mentioned above in point 2.

Please suggest what should be the good design - Design #1 or Design # 2.

Comment: A factory or manager pattern would allow you to use design #1, where the life cycle management is the sole responsibility of the factory or manager.  Of course, this could be encapsulating design #2...;)

Comment: *create*, *delete* and *update* are behaviors (methods). It makes more sense to have a *single* class and one or more helper classes supporting it instead of 3 classes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, So which design would you suggest?

Comment: @TheLostMind, but create update and delete are three different things and not cohesive, So when I do create, I dont need delete etc. So I feel they should go to diff classes.

Comment: Me, personally, I'd have a central manager responsible for the over life cycle of the object, but that's me...

Comment: @Manish - Your design is *indirectly* cohesive. You have to work only on the user. `Create`, `update` and `delete` cannot add anything new to the user. Your `Update` class can only contain methods that work on the methods already defined in the sue class.

Comment: @TheLostMind, if tomorrow I dont want deleteUser, I need to go and make changes in UserOperations, which is gonna be violation of OCP. If instead I have separate class, I dont need to touch userOperations so no violation of OCP, Right?

Comment: I don't think your example is the best. First, I don't think getting rid of deleteUser tomorrow is reasonable; you're likely going to want to hang on to that one. And that may be an indication which design is best. Following SRP to this degree unwinds OOP. If you think about it, there isn't many, if any, examples of classes anymore. They'd basically devolve to single-method-wrappers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with defining what a *responsibility* is, is well known. Robert Martin suggests to interpret it [like this](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html):

> The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) states that each software module should have one and only one reason to change

and also (the same link):

> When you write a software module, you want to make sure that when changes are requested, those changes can only originate from a single person, or rather, a single tightly coupled group of people representing a single narrowly defined business function.

In your example, changes in *business* requirements will concern at most *User* entity, not how its being managed in terms of implementation details. The important point of view is *what* your application does for the *people* using it, not how does it do it. That's why I also recommend the **first approach**. The commonly used pattern for this is called [The Repository](http://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/).

Comment: My opinion on this: desing #2 is a total no go. You should create a class "UserOperation" and it has one and only one responsability and that is "managing users". You should not exaggerate in creating different classes for different actions on a user object since they all are responsible for "the user". This is just in addition to the above correct answer.